# How is the CurrentExecutionFilepath set?

Tags: c#, .net, events, request

Im trying to understand how the CurrentExecutionFilepath is being set in

```
HttpContext.Current.Request
```

Please see the code below:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();
    if (url.Contains("disc") || url.Contains("default.aspx") || url.Contains("login.aspx"))
    {
        var blah = "test";
    }
}

void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();
    if (url.Contains("disc") || url.Contains("default.aspx") || url.Contains("login.aspx"))
    {
        var blah = "test";
    }
}

void Application_AuthorizeRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();
    if (url.Contains("disc") || url.Contains("default.aspx") || url.Contains("login.aspx"))
    {
        var blah = "test";
    }

    string rewrittenUrl = SiteContext.ReWriteUrl((HttpApplication)sender);
    if (rewrittenUrl != null)
        ((HttpApplication)sender).Context.RewritePath(rewrittenUrl);
}
```

These are three events that are executing logic in the Global.asax. Code in question here are each line where the following happens:

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();
```

This happens once in each method when I hit page X. In the BeginRequest event the `request.url` is `/X`, in the AuthenticateRequest event the `request.url` is `/X`. This the happens again except this time in all three events the `request.url` and `request.CurrentExecutionFilepath` is `/X.aspx`. This is what I want but I have no Idea how this is working? I have been tasked to work with this logic but i am not the person who wrote it so im a bit confused as to how it works. If anyone can help that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone experiencing something similar, it seems my issue is due to the Form Authentication in asp.net. There were some entries in the config that were directing unauthorised users to my /x.aspx page.